# Iterate over a collection of SQL table names

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database containing tables filled with information about transactions which took place in specific months and years.

A new table is created at the start of every month and follows the naming convention as follows **'tblposhistory201811'**. Each table created at the start of every month has the same structure, the only difference being the name of the table and the data inside.

The first part of the table name is always the same **'tblposhistory'** the second part of the table name changes every month and year. For instance **'201811'** means that the table was created for the transactions which took place in November of 2018.

I have managed to already be able to get the names of all the tables which follow this convention in the database. I have tried to look at a way to loop through the values I have collected but SQL only supports WHILE loops which makes my life tricky as I do not know how the values I collected with my code are stored in the variable table_names. Is it as a string or are they unique values which can be iterated over?

```
**SELECT** name **AS** table_names
**FROM** sys.tables
**WHERE** sys.tables.name **LIKE** 'tblposhistory%';
```

What I would like to be able to do is select all of the tables and their data which follow this naming convention, I would like to then be able to select more specific things from this data.

Comment: [SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)

Comment: Partitioning would be a better solution for this

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the heads up, I have added a tag!

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thanks, this looks like it could be the ticket!